# Error in creating mysql partitions

Tags: mysql, database-partitioning

When I tried to create a partition it shows me this error.

**SQL query:**

`CREATE TABLE t1(
id INT,
val INT
)PARTITION BY HASH(
val
)(
PARTITION p0 MAX_ROWS =200 MIN_ROWS =10,
PARTITION p1 MAX_ROWS =100 MIN_ROWS =20
)`

**MySQL said: Documentation**

`1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'PARTITION BY HASH(val)
(
PARTITION p0 MAX_ROWS=200 MIN_ROWS=10,
PARTITION' at line 2`

Please help me

Answer (score 2):

mysql 5.0 doesn't support partitioning.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning.html